# How to programmatically trigger the click on a link using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

How to programmatically trigger the click on a link using jQuery?

Comment: be careful of being flagged as a malicious site with javascript that does that... Clicking for a user is a very unhonourable thing to do

Comment: There are legit use cases for this. If the user has already clicked on something else to trigger a process that involves this click, and the user understands what is going on, I don't see the problem.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

```
$('#your_link_id').click()
```

See the excellent jquery [docs](http://api.jquery.com/click/) for more information

Answer (score 65):

If you have an anchor link:

```
<a id="my_link_id" href="something">My Link</a>
```

it will fail as other answers have mentioned. Calling .eq and .trigger('click') doesn't work for me, but this does:

```
$('#your_link_id').get(0).click();
```

In my specific case, I've assigned a blob url programmatically to the anchor's href.

Comment: After trying numerous different ways to click a span programmatically, this is the only one that works for me.

Comment: Thank you. Many years later this was a min-lifesaver.

Comment: This is the only one that worked for me. `.trigger("click")` executed the click event too many times that I would get an error: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: thank you. `.trigger("click")` didn't work me either. this does `.get(0).click();` :)

Comment: So does anyone can explain why .get(0).click() works and..click() doesn't?

Comment: `.click()` will call any jQuery event handlers you've defined.

`.get(0)` returns the DOM element, which you can then call the click method of (not related to jQuery).

Answer (score 26):

You can use [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/):

```
$('#your_link_id').trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 15):

```
$('#your_link_id').eq(0).trigger('click');
```

or you can use
$('#your_link_id')[0].trigger('click');

is needed as jQuery returns an array and we cannot trigger click on multiple eventlinks. You have to target only a single element

Comment: Actually this will throw an error since you're on a native element by specifying [0]. To use jQuery methods on a specific item in a collection use filter methods such as .eq(0) or .first(), or wrap the whole thing in another $(). ex: $('#your_link_id').eq(0).trigger('click')

Comment: Interestingly, Marcy's solution doesn't work for me, whereas Sandeep's does.  For some reason, $("#myDivIdentifier a").eq(0) still returns an array of one.  $("#myDivIdentifier a")[0] gives me a single item that can be "click()"ed.