# I want to open link Using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

**I want to open link using Jquery by clicking on anchor by using its anchor id in change function. Please help me to open it**

```
<div id="div1" style="display:none">
    <a id="0" href="http://www.friferie.dk/inspiration/Belgien">Belgium</a>
    <a id="1" href="http://www.friferie.dk/inspiration/Bulgarien">Bulgarien</a>
    <a id="2" href="http://www.friferie.dk/inspiration/Danmark">Danmark</a>
 </div>


         **I want to pass id then open particular href into it**    

    $ ("").change(function  ()  { 
}
```

Comment: What element is `change` connected to? That only works for certain `input` tags (`select` etc)

Comment: yes with select by a dropdown of a dropdownlist using its id

Comment: So the heart of this question is then clicking links programmatically.  Have you tried searching SO?  For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2847185/how-to-programmatically-trigger-the-click-on-a-link-using-jquery

Comment: @Ahmed not even in the HTML5 page.....?

Answer (score 1):

Long version (for readability):

```
$ ("#someselector").change(function  ()  { 
   // Get selected value
   var val = $(this).val();

   // Use the selected value to create a jQuery ID selector to get the link
   var link = $('#' + val);

   // get the href value
   var href = link.attr("href");

   // Change the browser location
   window.location = link;
});
```

Or simulate a link click:

```
$ ("#someselector").change(function  ()  { 
   // Get selected value
   var val = $(this).val();

   // Use the selected value to create a jQuery ID selector and get the link
   var link = $('#' + val);

   // Click the link
   link[0].click();
});
```

I tend to use `[0].click()` and not the jQuery `click()` here as it hits the underlying browser implementation (and we won't care about the jQuery extras as the page will change).

### Notes:

- Both examples can be shortened, e.g. by removing local variable, but this was for explanatory purposes

e.g.

```
$ ("#someselector").change(function  ()  { 
   window.location = $('#' + $(this).val()).attr("href");
});
```

or

```
$ ("#someselector").change(function  ()  { 
   $('#' + $(this).val())[0].click();    // Or `).click()` is you want it shorter
});
```

Answer (score 0):

*yes with select by a dropdown of a dropdownlist using its id*

As per this comment, you can do this :

```
$("#dropdown").change(function(e){ // change event on dropdown
   $('#'+this.value).click(); // and apply the click on specific anchor
   // $('#'+this.value).get(0).click(); // comparing to selected value
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div id="div1" style="display:none">
    <a id="0" href="#" onclick="onChange(this)">Belgium</a>
    <a id="1" href="#" onclick="onChange(this)">Bulgarien</a>
    <a id="2" href="#" onclick="onChange(this)">Danmark</a>
 </div>

<script>

function onChange(obj){
   var id= $(obj).attr("id");
   switch(id){
      case "0":
window.location.href="http://www.friferie.dk/inspiration/Belgien";
      break;

      case "1":
window.location.href="http://www.friferie.dk/inspiration/Bulgarien";
      break;

      case "2":
window.location.href="http://www.friferie.dk/inspiration/Danmark";
      break;
   }
}

</script>
```