# Click on div with javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a clickable div and I want to some how with javascript or jquery to be able to click on it automatically.

My div is like this:

```
<div style="display:none;" id="button">Hello</div>
```

That is click able div when display changed to block I need some script to do that for me.

I need some script like, when it sees that div display changed to block then script must click on div id="button"

I have tried this but this is not for that as I searched on google

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#button').trigger('click');
});

</script >
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to programmatically trigger the click on a link Using jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2847185/how-to-programmatically-trigger-the-click-on-a-link-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example in JS:

```html
<div style="display:none;" id="button">Hello</div>


<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var button = document.getElementById('button');
        
    button.addEventListener('click', function() {
      this.style.display = 'block';  
    })
        
    if (button.style.display === 'block') {
      button.click()
    }
  });
</script >
```

Update:

If you need to click on button after some javascript actions, just add there following lines:

```
if (button.style.display === 'block') {
  button.click()
}
```

Update2:

In the provided page I found the method to show mentioned `div`:

```
function startChecking() {
    secondsleft -= 1e3,
    document.querySelector(".load_stream").innerHTML = "Please Wait.. " + Math.abs(secondsleft / 1e3) + " Seconds",
0 == secondsleft && (clearInterval(interval),
    $(".reloadframe").show(),
    document.querySelector(".load_stream").style.display = "none",
    $("#btn_play_s").show()
    //You need to place it here, after "show" div will be displayed
    // and display will have value "block"
  )
}
```

So you can replace last line with `$('#btn_play_s').show().click()` instead of `$('#btn_play_s').show()`, it will be enough.

Comment: but i want it to check on div display like, when display = block then it must click on it

Comment: @ronaldocr could you please clarify `when it sees that div display changed to block`?

Comment: i will give you some example, now on page i have tht div above with style display:none i have a code on my page it will change after 10 seconds that display:none to display:block . so what i am asking from you to help me to find a code to make it like this,  when style became display:block then your code must click on that div

Comment: @ronaldocr you can just put `if (button.style.display === 'block') {
      button.click()
    };` to any place you're changing the display property of div

Comment: as you see this is one of my pages, http://tgo-tv.com/watch/channel/28.php after 10 seconds countdown this div will display " btn_play_s " on countdown is place and i placed your code at head section i don't know your code is not working or i placed i wrong

Comment: i have placed your code at head section. as you see what i mean is, your code must click on that div says "Click to Watch LIVE Stream" instead of i click on it manually

Comment: so if I get you correct, you would like to run video right after div"clck to watch" will be displayed? @ronaldocr

Comment: @ronaldocr I updated the answer, please, check the update2 :)

Comment: sorry for my late replay, yes that worked dear and that's a good trick. but as you see here that button will still be there, it must be gone if videos started automatically http://tgo-tv.com/watch/channel/28.php

Comment: and can i have your personal email dear ?

Comment: @ronaldocr well, to hide the button you can do something like this
`$('#btn_play_s').show().click().hide()`

As for my email for further help, it will not be for free, sorry :)

Comment: ok thanks a lot for all you did for me. and i askd for your email i don't have lots of designing work really just need sometimes a few editing etc.. well it's ok thanks a lot again.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `$('#button').click();` every where you want.

If you want to trigger this event when button display changed first you need create an event for this (because Jquery don't have on display changed event).
And then trigger it's your self:

```js
$('#button2').on('click',function(){
    $('#button')
    .css('display','block')
    .trigger('isVisible');
});

$('#button').bind('isVisible',function() {
   alert('Clicked...!');
});


$(function(){
    $('#button').click();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="button2" value="display the button"/>
<div style="display:none;" id="button">Hello</div>
```