# button click should open multiple

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I have a page with `<a>` links to download pdf files. Now I have to put a button to download all files available on that page. Now how to trigger a click event on all links on button click ?

```
    <button class="download-all"/>
    <a class="link" href="file.html"/>
    <a class="link" href="file2.html"/>
```

Now on button click all the links with `link` class should be clicked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to programmatically trigger the click on a link Using jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2847185/how-to-programmatically-trigger-the-click-on-a-link-using-jquery)

Comment: May I ask why you are trying to do this?

Comment: @Fredreik I have already said that in OP. I have links to download individual files, now i need to download them all at once.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is incorrect, Please modify with the below.

HTML,

```
<button type="button" class="button">Download All PDF</button>
<a class="link" href="file.html">PDF</a>
<a class="link" href="file2.html">PDF</a>
```

JS,

```
$('button.button').on('click', function(){
    $('a.link').click(); //fires click to all a with class "link"
});

//Anchor tag click Event
$('a.link').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr("id");
    window.location.href = href;
});
```

Comment: Yeah its a bit incorrect. I just wrote it as sample.

Comment: @SrujanSujju The above HTML structure is the correct one.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: click is not defined

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is possible using standard web technologies because HTTP does not support more than one file download at a once.

**Solution:-**

Open multiple amount of window to initiate the file download

Easiest way would be to serve the multiple files bundled up into a ZIP file.So onclick anyone can download the zip file.