# Using jQuery to click an <a> Tag

Tags: jquery

In my program, I have a `<button>` and I want it to click an `<a>` tag when clicked. I thought this code would work, but it didnt...

```
$("#button").click(function(){
    $("#a").trigger('click');
});
```

But it doesn't seem to actually cause the click to occur. Anybody know how to do this in chrome?

Comment: @Satpal yeah it is, and the answer you posted is in the duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23097260/519413

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.trigger("click")` will not actually click the element, it will only trigger click handler attached with the element.

Use native `click()`

```
 $("#a").get(0).click(); //get(0) returns reference to DOM element
```